# scroll webview to the top after url load

Tags: android, scroll, webview

I'm working on an application that uses a webview to show pages that the user can navigate using simple buttons. I'm facing a problem where after the button is pressed and another page is loaded, the webview doesn't scroll up to the top of the page, but remembers the scroll position of the last page.

I think the solution should be this code, but it seems to not be working, all I want to do is scroll up after the page was loaded:

```
void openWebPage(String pageName) {
    try {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + pageName);
        if (!webView.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled()) {
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //Enable js
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebInterface(this), "Android");
        }
        //scroll up,  must be delayed after page load
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                view.scrollTo(0, 0);
                //view.computeScroll();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        toast("Errore nell'apertura della pagina.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks anybody for the help.

Comment: try to do make it via postDelayed view.postDelayed(new Runnable() { view.scrollTo(0, 0); },<some value>);

Comment: unfortunatly it's not working either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was that in my layout I wrapped the webview inside a scrollbar, for some reason doing this messed up the call and the content length of the webview never changed.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same. I really  need the `ScrollView`, so I made it so that I do a `scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this one onPageFinished Method

'''
scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
'''